# How to access nested field in ingest node pipeline?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I need to access the field "kind" and it's nested I have shared how the data in json looks like. I want to use a set processor in ingest node pipelines and add a new field if this has a value pod. How do I achieve this?

```
 "kubernetes": {
  "event": {
    "type": "Normal",
    "count": 1,
    "source": {
      "host": "worker",
      "component": "kubelet"
    },
    "involved_object": {
      "uid": "1d7add39-6569-450t-a3dc-886e063bfcca",
      "api_version": "v1",
      "resource_version": "92916573314",
      "name": "hello-world",
      "kind": "Pod"
    }
 }
}
```

Tried to use the below condition in the set processor but it does not work

```
ctx.kubernetes?.event?.involved_object?.kind=="Pod"
ctx.kubernetes.event.involved_object.kind=="Pod"
```

Ingest pipeline I created :

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/prometheus-kubify
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "kubernetes.namespace",
        "ignore_empty_value": true,
        "if": "ctx.metricset.name==\"query\"",
        "ignore_failure": true,
        "copy_from": "prometheus.labels.namespace"
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "kubernetes.pod.name",
        "copy_from": "prometheus.labels.pod",
        "ignore_empty_value": true,
        "if": "ctx.metricset.name==\"query\"",
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "kubernetes.container.name",
        "copy_from": "prometheus.labels.container",
        "ignore_empty_value": true,
        "if": "ctx.metricset.name==\"query\"",
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "kubernetes.namespace",
        "copy_from": "kubernetes.event.metadata.namespace",
        "ignore_empty_value": true,
        "if": "ctx.kubernetes.event.involved_object.kind==\"Pod\"",
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "kubernetes.pod.name",
        "ignore_empty_value": true,
        "if": "ctx.kubernetes.event.involved_object.kind==\"Pod\"",
        "ignore_failure": true,
        "copy_from": "kubernetes.event.involved_object.name"
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "kubernetes.deployment.name",
        "copy_from": "kubernetes.event.involved_object.name",
        "ignore_empty_value": true,
        "if": "ctx.kubernetes.event.involved_object.kind==\"Deployment\"",
        "ignore_failure": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your condition looks correct, what makes you think that it didn't work?

Comment: the first one right? It works when I test within the ingest node pipeline but when I save it and check-in discover it's working for only 10% of the data.

Comment: Then it's working and there's something in the other 90% of the data for which this condition is not satisfied. It's easy to pick one of those docs and investigate why. Show us one

Comment: I tried to pick one which does not work but when I test the same doc it's working fine. Could this be an issue of ingest node ?

Comment: Maybe show your ingest pipeline, maybe it's another processor causing this?

Comment: updated the pipeline

Comment: Can you also show a sample document that wasn't properly updated as you expected?